# Daily Yoga routine

Tags: yoga, routine

I wish to find some universal yoga complex for every day, for 30-45 min. to do it at home to make it a habit. I wached a lot of videos, read a lot, even loaded a mobile app. with different sessions and now i fell myself lost in all the information. Can you help me somehow?

Comment: Please help me by describing exactly what the question is.  What more could you want other than the videos?

Comment: Some general rules to make a program for me would be great! "start - middle - end". As i understood yoga has its main principles. But all i found looks like just free move changes, from pose to pose.

Comment: I understand that better to find a good school and to practice, to read, but its important for me to understand by my own how i can get yoga in my usual life, becouse i travell a lot and cant just go to some yoga class.

Comment: I understand.  Once you understand the practice of Yoga and what you're attempting to accomplish, you won't need a book or a class.  You perform all of those moves for the several minutes of calm which follows.

Comment: Not exactly yoga, but if you just wish to stretch, consider the [Starting Stretching](http://phraktured.net/starting-stretching.html) routine.

Comment: Dan, thx! Inspiration lives in your words.

Comment: VPeric, thx, ill try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not easy to build your own practice, but it is well worth the effort. Once established, you'll have much more benefit compared to someone who occasionally visits yoga classes.

There are a few things that need to be addressed when building the practice of your own:

- Discipline: you need to get on the mat, day in, day out. This doesn't just mean perseverance, you need to figure yourself out - what you want, what motivates you.
- Correct execution of poses: understand how each pose works anatomically and how to do them correctly. The poses are not supposed to look like you see it on the pictures, often you need to adapt them for your own body. This is the hardest part to do by yourself, so at least occasionally try to visit a teacher to check your form.
- Remembering the sequence: learn sequences by heart. It takes some time to memorize, prints, videos come in handy.
- Keeping up the flow
- Keeping it challenging

I'd suggest to start with a system which has fixed sequences. It helps with the discipline, and there's less to think about. Ashtanga yoga has fixed sequences, but the ashtanga sequences are long (up to 90-120 min). David Swenson has a number of  [15, 30, 45 minute routines](http://www.dailycupofyoga.com/2011/03/08/ashtanga-yoga-short-forms-with-david-swenson/) which are cut-down versions of the ashtanga series, designed for people short on time.

You'll probably need to start practicing along with a book or dvd until you remember the poses. There's an ocean of material out there, just a few:

- [Total Ashtanga by Tara Fraser](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1844831132)
- [Ashtanga Yoga Primary Series by Mark Darby](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006I036C)
- [Ashtanga Yoga: The Practice Manual by David Swenson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1891252089)

Good luck!

Comment: Super! Your answer covers all my subquestions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you can get your hand on P90X Yoga, give it a try; it's an hour and half though.
It has all the yoga moves you've seen in other programs, and the movements are slow and steady. The instructor also shows you modified versions of the moves, just in case you are not strong enough to perform the hard ones. 
 
It also has some extra exercises, specifically designed for the core/abs, as well as stretch exercises.
 
The only downside is the duration; it's too long (an hour and half); but you can always forward it to the specific exercises you want or perform it on the days you have ample time. 
 
The video really helps with your flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

A solid Hatha yoga practice includes forward bending poses, backward bending poses, twists, balancing poses and inversion poses, as finishes with the corpse pose.  There are hundreds of postures to choose from, some of which are more suitable for beginners and some of which are more advanced.  If you have done a practice with videos and taken any classes you are already familiar with the poses that are both comfortable and a bit challenging.  Make a list of the 3 forward bending poses and 3 backward bending poses, 1 twisting pose, 2 balancing poses and 1 inversion to do as part of your practice daily.  The poses should be the ones that are slightly challenging but not painfully so.  Make several lists which include various postures of the five types.  Change from one list to the other once in a while.  Regular practice will definitely enhance your ability to do the poses.  Videos are OK for learning, but practice is most yogic in quiet solitude.